# hide a transparent :before div on hover

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a div that displays an image and then has a half height semi transparent block on which I write text. This is done using some code from this site that utilizes "before". How do I hide this transparent block on hover? I've tried all I can think of. I can't use a standard transparent image because the image is different on each instance of the div and they aren't on site. The use of :before in this way is not something I fully understand but suspect it is complicating matters.

```
.summary_props_trans {
   position: relative; 
   font-family:'Melbourne', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 2vmin;
   color: black;
   font-weight:normal;
   z-index: 0;  
   width: 220px;
   height: 165px;
   margin: 5px;
   float: left;
   padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;  
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
   border-radius: 4px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.summary_props_trans:hover {
   filter:alpha(opacity=80);  
   -moz-opacity:0.8;  
   -khtml-opacity: 0.8;  
   opacity: 0.8; 
}

.summary_props_trans:before{
   content:''; 
   display: block;
   position: absolute; 
   background: white; 
   opacity: .5;
   filter:alpha(opacity=50);
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
   margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply wish to apply styles to `.summary_props_trans` `:befor`e pseudo-element when the `.summary_props_trans` element matches a pseudo-class, you need to write `.summary_props_trans:hover:before` or `.summary_props_trans:visited:before` instead. Notice the pseudo-element comes after the pseudo-class (and in fact, at the very end of the entire selector).

so, Simply add

```
.summary_props_trans:hover:before{
    display:none;
}
```

or

```
.summary_props_trans:hover:before {
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);  
  -moz-opacity:0;  
  -khtml-opacity: 0;  
  opacity: 0; 
}
```

Here's an Example http://jsfiddle.net/dyaa/kn0z52ya/

Comment: Have I not done? Perhaps you are just too quick. Your answer encouraged me into research on pseudo classes. I should have know that really but just didn't put 2 and 2 together. There's lots but I'm not sure how to make the most of them! Thanks again.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain why: .summary_props_trans:hover:before + table tr td {
    display:none;
}  doesn't hide the table also? the div is a transparent background for a table over an image. Your code allows me to hide the background but I'd like to hide the table on hover also. I know this is additional so your answer is still good.